# Nginx UI problem with proxy routing when forwarding host/path to specific port

Tags: docker, nginx, raspberry-pi3, nginx-reverse-proxy

Now the Problem is as shown in the below pictures i need to port forward my incoming trafic from my NOIP domain **kucna-mreza.ddns.net** to my portainer which is located on the same device and the locak ip is **192.168.2.15** portainer port is **9000** and when i do just one it works normnally now when i try to forward the **kucna-mreza.ddns.net/omv** to port **192.168.2.15:8441** it just doesnt work and i get **404** error.

I have even tried to set it up as **omv.kucna-mreza.ddns.net** which i presume is the proper way but i still cant get it to work.

Any sugestions how to make it work for my portainer plex and openmediavault?
*By the way the plex is set up as a host network in my docker instalation.*

I also presume you need me to give you the specifics on the setup i have and i am aware this is a bad setup but its for my home network and i kinda works the way i have set it up for now is that i acces everything using kucna-mreza.ddns.net:port and port forward everything. I am running an **OpenMediaVault** instalation on my **raspberry pi 3b+** and i have connected to id external ssd inside **OMV** installed the **omv extras** and **docker** and **portainer** and it all works. And i am trying to use Nginx Proxy manager for the proxy hosts.

[image: Portainer Containers]

Also i have tried to reach every container from my nginx console and i am able to curl the data as shown bellow.

[image: Port 9000 - Portainer]

[image: Port 8441 - OpenMediaVault]

[image: Port 32400 - Plex Media Server]

And this is what i have tried to set up in Nginx

[image: Nginx current configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Well i solved it apparently it wasnt a problem on my server at all the NOIP domain name hasnt been set up to forward wildcards. Done that and everything works now.